# cannot install uinput on raspberry pi

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, pip, uinput

I'm trying to install uinput and found the command I need to run (`pip install python-uinput`)

except that I get this error when I try to run it:

```
Cannot fetch index base URL https://pypi.python.org/simple/
Could not find any downloads that satisfy the requirement python-uinput
No distributions at all found for python-uinput
Storing complete log in /root/.pip/pip.log
```

does anybody know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You mention running RaspberryPi but the log path is Windows one. Did you run it on correct machine?

Comment: I just copy pasted the log from another answer, sorry about that

Answer (score 2):

You can install the library manually. The official webpage says [how to do it](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/).

Basically you download the [provided tarball](http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/releases/) unpack it and run the setup script.

Fastest way to download the tarball is using the program wget:

`wget http://tjjr.fi/sw/python-uinput/releases/python-uinput-0.10.2.tar.gz`

then to unpack it you run

`tar -xzf python-uinput-0.10.2.tar.gz`

and at last you build and install the module:

```
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

It seems that some dependent libraries are missing on your RPi. I needed to install `libudev-dev` to got the module to build the module.

Comment: how do I download the tarball on the raspberry pi, do I have to download it on windows and then put it on a usb stick?

Comment: I was finally able to test on the raspberry and when I try to build it, It says that ev.py is missing

Comment: According this thread (https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=75681&p=541203), it should work fine. Check which python version you have. Maybe it's the problem.

Comment: okay, I got further, now I have the error command "gcc" failed with exit status 1

Comment: Did you get any error log from GCC? Have you tried running it with root privileges?

Comment: I don't even know what GCC is, I got that error while running python setup.py build in the folder with the file

Comment: GCC is a C compiler, the uinput needs some low level C stuff to work, so it needs to compile part of its code. I've tried it on my PC (Xubuntu 14.04) and it seems you need to install libudev-dev package. Run `sudo apt-get install libudev-dev` to install the missing package. And then run the python install again.